# Available variable does not render on my AppBar but renders on other components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Google Firebase and UserAuthContext.js

```
....
  return (
<userAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, authenticatedUser, logIn, signUp, logOut }}>
  {children}
</userAuthContext.Provider>
);
....
```

I have an AppBar Component and get the data like this:

```
  const { user, authenticatedUser, logOut } = useUserAuth();
  console.log(authenticatedUser)
```

The data "authenticatedUser" is available. Everything is correct.

When I am trying to display the data like this:

```
{authenticatedUserr && authenticatedUserr.userState && authenticatedUserr.userState.userUsername}
```

I do not get the variable displayed. **It will be displayed, when I open a notification component on my AppBar or when I switch to another component with ReactRouter.**

It will also be initially displayed in my "Home" component which is within the same hierachy with my "AppBar" component.

Why is the variable not initiallty displayed on my AppBar Component when its visible with the same method on other components?

Added Log result:

```
{
    "userState": {
        "userUsername": "depp",
        "userDateOfBirth": {
        "seconds": 1457046000,
        "nanoseconds": 567000000
    },
    "userUid": "fwaFiUdCzeY6YFo1JN25cIaRLPW2",
    "userBabyBadge": true,
    "userMarryBadge": true,
    "userPresentBadge": true,
    "userProfilePicture": "",
    "userVerified": true,
    "userIsSeller": true,
    "userRewardLevel": 10
    }
}
```

Edit: Image
[image]

Edit:
Source on "Home"

```
<Typography
        variant="h6"
        sx={{
          mr: 2,
          display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
          fontWeight: 700,
          letterSpacing: ".3rem",
          color: white,
          textDecoration: "none",
        }}
      >
        HERE is it!
        {authenticatedUserr &&
          authenticatedUserr.userState &&
          authenticatedUserr.userState.userUsername}
      </Typography>
```

Edit:
Source on "AppBar"

```
<Typography
  variant="h6"
  noWrap
  component={Link}
  to="/"
  sx={{
  mr: 2,
  display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
  fontWeight: 700,
  letterSpacing: ".3rem",
  color: white,
  textDecoration: "none",
  }}
   >
   No Username?! Should be HERE:
   {authenticatedUserr &&
    authenticatedUserr.userState &&
    authenticatedUserr.userState.userUsername}
   </Typography>;
```

Comment: What do you see if console.log `authenticatedUser.userState.userUsername`? I'm not sure how things are behaving, but it sound like there may be a promise somewhere that needs to be awaited. That could explain why the value is not there, and then it appears later.

Comment: @adam.k I have added the log result. But wouldnt it then not appearing on any component? It works on e v e r y component, except my AppBar..?

Comment: @adam.k I think you are somehow correct. in <Home> I have, to simulate something, a setTimeOut() on 2 seconds. With removing the function, it also will not appear. Do you have any idea, how to fix? My data gets loaded first, then rendering will happen

Comment: I'd have see more of the component. When you `console.log(authenticatedUser)`, does this log out twice? First time it is empty, the next with the values you posted above? If you don't see it logging twice, try `console.log("check", authenticatedUser)`. If it is logging twice (one empty, one with values), that means there is a promise that does not resolve till after the first render. I'd need to look at more of the components to determine why. I suggest looking at how/when `authenticatedUser` gets it's values, and read up on Promises/async programming if not familiar with it